# MKMapView callout bug in iOS7+

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

An annotationView opens callout only after I rotate a little bit the map. Otherwise it only moves the map and shows only the white triangle.
This bug exists only in iOS7. In iOS 6 it works good.
Any help?

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
PBAnnotation *pbAnnotation = (PBAnnotation *)annotation;
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = nil;
if (annotation != _mapView.userLocation) {
    static NSString *ReusableViewId = @"PBAnnotation";
    annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:ReusableViewId];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:pbAnnotation reuseIdentifier:ReusableViewId];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

        switch (pbAnnotation.type) {
            case TypeHotel:
                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin-hotel"];
                break;
            case TypeRestaurant:
                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin-rest"];
                break;
            case TypeStore:
                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin-store"];
                break;
            case TypeTourSite:
                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin-site"];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}

return annotationView;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have found a bug then please report it to https://bugreport.apple.com . In the meantime please show your `MKMapViewDelegate` methods otherwise SO cannot help to find a workaround.

Comment: I am not sure about your main question (perhaps you're doing something special in didSelectAnnotationView?) but you have a problem with your image-setting logic.  Code is only setting the image when creating a new view.  If a view is dequeued, it does not update the view's annotation property or the image which means an annotation could show the wrong image.  This problem may shown up when you zoom or pan the map.

Comment: The problem occurs on initial loading. After I rotate the map, even without dequeueing the annotation, the problem resolves.

Comment: My first comment was explaining about an unrelated problem I see in the code with view re-use which has nothing to do with your main question.

Comment: Based on your latest comment and regarding your main question about the callout: Are you perhaps calling `selectAnnotation` when initially loading the annotations?  If this is being done from a background thread, it may cause this UI issue.